# How often do you run VACUUM FULL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm running PostgreSQL 10 on AWS for a couple years in production and wondering if it's worth the downtime to perform a VACUUM FULL on the database.

Comment: I personally have a twice-monthly schedule where we isolate candidate tables and issue table-specific `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` statements. Our databases have MVCC-unfriendly behavior, though (day-long transactions with tens of millions of row changes).

Comment: What's your workload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you never have to run `VACUUM (FULL)`. It is only necessary if the tables have become unduly bloated, either because of autovacuum being too slow or because of mass updates.

I would examine the tables you suspect to be bloated with [`pgstattuple`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstattuple.html) to see how big `free_percent` is.

20% bloat is normal. Consider `VACUUM (FULL)` only if you have much more bloat.